# Bootstrap Styles Not Working with IE

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, telerik

I have a small web application deployed on IIS. When viewed with IE, the Bootstrap styling for the navbar and a primary button don't work. When viewed with Chrome, everything works fine. Likewise, when viewed with IE on my development machine using IIS Express, everything works fine.

Using IE against the IIS server, the navbar height is twice the normal size, as is the primary button. Also the primary button does not have rounded corners per the selected theme. However, both of the controls are the right color.

There are also two Telerik Kendo components on the page, and they display the same problem. Moreover, the Telerik Upload component doesn't work correctly.

Fiddler shows the Content and bootstrap bundles getting loaded, and I have even tried loading the individual files from _Layout.cshtml. Likewise, IE developer tools shows the bundle references.

Comment: which version of IE? which version of Bootstrap? Which Kendo components and which version? Also - without looking at your code it's really hard to help. Add a working example (you can use jsfiddle.net for that).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

The problem is resolved by adding the following metatag to the page header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: There was some issues with my css. I changed them and now it works fine.

Comment: That is not the solution.